# How can I check for PHP classes whose file names and paths do not match their full namespace (with case sensitivity)

Tags: php

I have a large PHP project with an unknown number of instances of file names and / or paths that do not match up with the full namespace of the class.

All instances I've come across so far are due to mismatches with case (eg Api vs API).

Is there an easy way I can scan the entire project to identify these mismatches?

A simple console-based tool would be ideal, so it could be run automatically as part of another process.

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: are you using an IDE? What are you hoping to use to scan?

Comment: Something in the terminal that just lists the problematic files would be ideal, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, you could try a simple regex search like `new\s+\w+`. This wont catch everything of course, but might be a good start.

Comment: Any map-based autoloader might help (`phpab`, `composer dump-autoload -a`) in deciding which way to fix or further the non-unixy path casing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every file in your project is loaded (`include` or `require`), you could try using the `get_declared_classes()` function to get the declared class names, then use `ReflectionClass` classes to check the `ReflectionClass::getFileName()` and compare them to the class names.

One thing to pay attention to is to skip every class where `ReflectionClass::isInternal()` returns true, because those classes are either default PHP classes and come from extensions, therefore they're not from PHP files (the method will return `false` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Simple command to find namespace and path mismatch (run from the project root; replace first asterisk with selected dirs if needed):

`grep -rP '^\s*namespace' * | sed 's|\\|/|g' | sed 's|/\w*\.php:namespace||' | grep -vP '^([a-zA-Z/_]+) \1;'`